# Passenger taking 100% of CPU, "This website is under heavy load (queue full)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, production-environment, passenger-nginx

I have a production rails 6.0.3, ruby 2.6.3 application with nginx and passenger. The app ran fine for ages until recently, the server began getting it's CPU maxed out. I used htop to see what is happening and I see several processes that are "Passenger AppPreloader: /app-location (forking...)"

I ran passenger-status and got

```
    /app-location (production):
  App root: /app-location
  Requests in queue: 3
  * PID: 2241    Sessions: 1       Processed: 8652    Uptime: 1h 0m 43s
    CPU: 26%     Memory  : 149M    Last used: 1s ago
  * PID: 2261    Sessions: 1       Processed: 8366    Uptime: 1h 0m 42s
    CPU: 24%     Memory  : 128M    Last used: 2s ago
  * PID: 2281    Sessions: 1       Processed: 7771    Uptime: 1h 0m 41s
    CPU: 22%     Memory  : 139M    Last used: 1s ago
  * PID: 2300    Sessions: 1       Processed: 7184    Uptime: 1h 0m 40s
    CPU: 20%     Memory  : 128M    Last used: 2s ago
  * PID: 2319    Sessions: 1       Processed: 6466    Uptime: 1h 0m 39s
    CPU: 19%     Memory  : 138M    Last used: 0s ago
  * PID: 2340    Sessions: 1       Processed: 6447    Uptime: 1h 0m 37s
    CPU: 18%     Memory  : 129M    Last used: 3s ago
  * PID: 2359    Sessions: 1       Processed: 6015    Uptime: 1h 0m 34s
    CPU: 17%     Memory  : 128M    Last used: 2s ago
  * PID: 2380    Sessions: 1       Processed: 5708    Uptime: 1h 0m 32s
    CPU: 16%     Memory  : 127M    Last used: 0s ago
```

Then ran passenger-status --show=server and got

```
    Version : 6.0.7
Date    : 2023-08-18 16:06:52 +0000
Instance: NTbICiN4 (nginx/1.14.0 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.7)

{
   "thread1" : {
      "active_client_count" : 5,
      "active_clients" : {
         "1-58219" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
               "relative" : "1s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -1.0689136981964111,
               "timestamp" : 1692374811.062485
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -1.0689136981964111,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.062459
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "1ae645d-fY1k189UHN",
                  "pid" : 2241
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -1.0689136981964111,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.062469
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "1-58219",
            "number" : 58219,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         },
         "1-58225" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
               "relative" : "1s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -0.66239261627197266,
               "timestamp" : 1692374811.468967
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.66239261627197266,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.468941
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "1ae645d-wHSs0mT5ZT",
                  "pid" : 2319
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.66239261627197266,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.4689519
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "1-58225",
            "number" : 58225,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         },
         "1-58226" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
               "relative" : "1s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -0.65522408485412598,
               "timestamp" : 1692374811.4760959
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.65522408485412598,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.4760671
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "1ae645d-9aPZQq2rjB",
                  "pid" : 2380
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.65522408485412598,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.4760759
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "1-58226",
            "number" : 58226,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         },
         "1-58227" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
               "relative" : "1s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -0.51140403747558594,
               "timestamp" : 1692374811.619869
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.51140403747558594,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.6198339
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "1ae645d-GzqZSvASHc",
                  "pid" : 2300
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.51140403747558594,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.6198471
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "1-58227",
            "number" : 58227,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         },
         "1-58237" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:52 2023",
               "relative" : "0s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -0.027449846267700195,
               "timestamp" : 1692374812.10377
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : false,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : true,
                  "initialized" : false,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:52 2023",
                  "relative" : "0s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.027449846267700195,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374812.1037059
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 2,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session_checkout_try" : 0,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:52 2023",
                  "relative" : "0s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.027449846267700195,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374812.1037469
               },
               "state" : "CHECKING_OUT_SESSION",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "1-58237",
            "number" : 58237,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         }
      },
      "client_accept_speed" : {
         "1h" : {
            "averaged_over" : "1 hour",
            "per" : "minute",
            "value" : 989.09000000000003
         },
         "1m" : {
            "averaged_over" : "1 minute",
            "per" : "minute",
            "value" : 1233.3800000000001
         }
      },
      "disconnected_client_count" : 0,
      "disconnected_clients" : {},
      "free_client_count" : 0,
      "free_request_count" : 6,
      "mbuf_pool" : {
         "active_blocks" : 5,
         "active_memory" : {
            "bytes" : 20480,
            "human_readable" : "20.0 KB"
         },
         "chunk_size" : 4096,
         "free_blocks" : 60,
         "offset" : 4048,
         "spare_memory" : {
            "bytes" : 245760,
            "human_readable" : "240.0 KB"
         }
      },
      "peak_active_client_count" : 11,
      "pid" : 1003,
      "request_begin_speed" : {
         "1h" : {
            "averaged_over" : "1 hour",
            "per" : "minute",
            "value" : 989.09000000000003
         },
         "1m" : {
            "averaged_over" : "1 minute",
            "per" : "minute",
            "value" : 1233.3800000000001
         }
      },
      "server_state" : "ACTIVE",
      "total_bytes_consumed" : 139872386,
      "total_clients_accepted" : 58237,
      "total_requests_begun" : 58237,
      "turbocaching" : {
         "fetches" : 0,
         "hit_ratio" : null,
         "hits" : 0,
         "store_success_ratio" : 0.0,
         "store_successes" : 0,
         "stores" : 0
      }
   },
   "thread2" : {
      "active_client_count" : 6,
      "active_clients" : {
         "2-58209" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:50 2023",
               "relative" : "2s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -1.711137056350708,
               "timestamp" : 1692374810.4202621
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:50 2023",
                  "relative" : "2s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -1.711137056350708,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374810.420238
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "1ae645d-tEcEtQ3OxQ",
                  "pid" : 2281
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:50 2023",
                  "relative" : "2s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -1.711137056350708,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374810.420249
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "2-58209",
            "number" : 58209,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         },
         "2-58219" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
               "relative" : "1s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -1.0652401447296143,
               "timestamp" : 1692374811.0661211
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -1.0652401447296143,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.0660989
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "1ae645d-m8VNsKoLer",
                  "pid" : 2340
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -1.0652401447296143,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.0661099
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "2-58219",
            "number" : 58219,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         },
         "2-58223" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
               "relative" : "1s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -0.76185989379882812,
               "timestamp" : 1692374811.3694699
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.76185989379882812,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.369447
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "1ae645d-TSVuBVnnU7",
                  "pid" : 2359
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.76185989379882812,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.369457
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "2-58223",
            "number" : 58223,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         },
         "2-58224" : {
            "connected_at" : {
               "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
               "relative" : "1s ago",
               "relative_timestamp" : -0.67304801940917969,
               "timestamp" : 1692374811.4582491
            },
            "connection_state" : "ACTIVE",
            "current_request" : {
               "app_response_http_state" : "PARSING_HEADERS",
               "app_sink_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : false
               },
               "app_source_state" : {
                  "callback_in_progress" : false,
                  "initialized" : true,
                  "io_watcher_active" : true
               },
               "flags" : {
                  "dechunk_response" : true,
                  "https" : true,
                  "request_body_buffering" : false
               },
               "host" : "www.hostname.com",
               "http_major" : 1,
               "http_minor" : 1,
               "http_state" : "COMPLETE",
               "last_data_receive_time" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.67304801940917969,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.458221
               },
               "last_data_send_time" : null,
               "method" : "GET",
               "path" : "/uri",
               "refcount" : 1,
               "request_body_already_read" : 0,
               "request_body_fully_read" : true,
               "request_body_type" : "NO_BODY",
               "response_begun" : false,
               "session" : {
                  "gupid" : "1ae645d-QZeDNIDYRj",
                  "pid" : 2261
               },
               "session_checkout_try" : 1,
               "started_at" : {
                  "local" : "Fri Aug 18 16:06:51 2023",
                  "relative" : "1s ago",
                  "relative_timestamp" : -0.67304801940917969,
                  "timestamp" : 1692374811.458231
               },
               "state" : "WAITING_FOR_APP_OUTPUT",
               "sticky_session" : false,
               "want_keep_alive" : false
            },
            "lingering_request_count" : 0,
            "name" : "2-58224",
            "number" : 58224,
            "output_channel_state" : {
               "bytes_buffered" : {
                  "bytes" : 0,
                  "human_readable" : "0 bytes"
               },
               "callback_in_progress" : false,
               "mode" : "IN_MEMORY_MODE",
               "nbuffers" : 0,
               "reader_state" : "RS_INACTIVE"
            },
            "refcount" : 2,
            "requests_begun" : 1
         },
       ...
       ...
   },
   "threads" : 2
}
```

Does anyone know of a lead to fix this issue? Thanks